# Can no longer select a port in Arduino IDE on Linux?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, linux

I am trying to upload to my Elegoo Mega 2560. I previously had it set up properly with the board installed and selected and the port automatically detected.

Now when I go to Tools and hover my mouse over Port nothing happens. I don't get an additional menu showing the port that is detected.

At the bottom of the IDE it says:

```
Arduino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega2560) on /dev/ttyACM0
```

But when I attempt to upload i get this error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Bad file descriptor
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Bad file descriptor
avrdude: stk500_send(): failed to send command to serial port
```

When I run the following command:

```
ls /dev | grep ttyACM0
```

I get no output and error code 1, which indicates that this port doesn't exist. The board is plugged in and some leds are lit up so it is receiving power. I tried reinstalling the drivers via board manager and deleting the files in the arduino15 directory and reinstalling the drivers. I've tried uninstalling and installing arduino ide all together but I still get the same error.

Why does it think it is at /dev/ttyACM0 but then at the same time it can't access it on this port?

This isn't working on my arch linux machine. Plugging the same board into a windows 10 machine and uploading the same code works just fine.

After reinstalling Arduino IDE on Arch Linux it no longer shows the board at ttyACM0 instead just showing a '-'

Comment: The output from `dmesg` might be helpful.

Comment: the IDE remembers the last selected port even if the port is no longer available. don't get distracted by that and do the common port-not-available trouble shooting. try different USB cable, USB connector, computer...